# Use different UV mapping with multiple textures

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

I am tring to set two different texture on a cylinder. The first texture has a text on it, the second is a paper cardboard texure.
In order to center the text in the first texture I had to select faces and scale them up, in order to make the text smaller.
Then I added the second Texture and I noticed that it has the same the mapping of the first texture:

[image: Difference]

You can clearly see that the cardboard texture has been scaled.

Is there a correct way to do this?

My shader:
[image]

UV Mapping:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moment, the text and the background texture share the same UV, so what you're doing is just scaling the UV for both the text and the background texture.

If you want to put a text over a background texture without affecting the texture you need to use another method, like mixing the text and background into a *Mix Shader* with the alpha of the text as factor of the *Mix Shader*, then create a second UV map for the text and use a *UV Map* node before the text node with this second UV map selected.

Comment: Thanks! It was easy, I just had to change the "Texture Coordinate" node with "UV Map" and create two different UV Maps from the Object Data Properties list